# the downloaded file is corrupt

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I write a script to download certain files from multiple pages from the web. The downloads seems to work but all the files corrupted. I tried different way to download the files but always give me corrupted files and all the files size only 4 kb.

Where do I need to change or revise my code to fix download's problem?

```py
while pageCounter < 3:
    soup_level1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    for div in soup_level1.findAll('div', attrs ={'class':'financial-report-download ng-scope'}):
        links = div.findAll('a', attrs = {'class':'ng-binding'}, href=re.compile("FinancialStatement"))
        for a in links:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@ng-repeat = 'attachments in res.Attachments']").click()
            files = [url + a['href']]
            for file in files:
                file_name = file.split('/')[-1]    

                print ("Downloading file:%s"%file_name)

                # create response object 
                r = requests.get(file, stream = True) 

                # download started 
                with open(file_name, 'wb') as f: 
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024): 
                        if chunk: 
                            f.write(chunk)

                print ("%s downloaded!\n"%file_name)
```

Comment: open file in text editor. Maybe you got HTML/text with captcha or warning that they don't like scripts/bots so they block your requests.

Comment: agree with @furas, it happens a lot when you use request directly .   change the default User-Agent and increase your download  interval may help

Comment: Thank you, @bigdataolddriver, tried that then i found another example of code and fix it with addition of r.raise_for_status(). actually i dont know exactly why since from the documentation [link](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) explained about Raises stored HTTPError and do not know the relation between raise an exception and downloading files